# In flutter, using PictureRecorder to draw picture will cause the memory to be unreleased

Tags: image, flutter, canvas, memory

I use Canvas to do some special drawing of the image and then save.
When I call `picture.toImage`, the memory will not fall back.
It seems that `picutre.toImage` has cached the image, can we release this cache？

```
  void _getImage() async {
    final imageFile = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (imageFile == null) {
      return;
    }
    Uint8List bytes = await imageFile.readAsBytes();
    final Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer();
    ui.decodeImageFromList(bytes, (ui.Image img) {
      return completer.complete(img);
    });
    ui.Image image = await completer.future;

    Size size = Size(image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble());
    final recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    final canvas = Canvas(
        recorder,
        Rect.fromLTWH(
            0, 0, image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble()));
    canvas.drawImageRect(
        image,
        ui.Rect.fromLTWH(
            0, 0, image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble()),
        ui.Rect.fromLTWH(
            0, 0, image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble()),
        Paint());

    image.dispose();
    ui.Picture picture = recorder.endRecording();
    final resutImage =
        await picture.toImage(size.width.toInt(), size.height.toInt());
    picture.dispose();
    resutImage.dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

dart:ui Pictures can retain SkImage objects, causing increased GPU memory usage
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28912

try dispose()